# In Django, how do you pass parameters from the URL to get_file() in VirtualDownloadView?

Tags: python, django, django-views

The below is parts of my Django project.

I've got the following URL configured.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^download/(?P<job>[0-9]+)/$', DownloadJobResults.as_view(), name='dm_download')
)
```

And the following is the DownloadJobResults class.

```
class DownloadJobResults(VirtualDownloadView):

    def get_file(self, job):

        print "Job is {}".format(job)

        file = StringIO.StringIO()
        file.write("test 1,2,3,4\n")
        file.write("test 5,6,7,8\n")
        file.seek(0)
        return VirtualFile(file, name='sweet.txt')
```

I'll eventually be using the job parameter to look up job data and return a file with it. But I can't get the parameter passed. When I access that URL, I get:

> get_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Here is the full stack trace.

```
Traceback: File "/Users/michael/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/michael/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/michael/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/michael/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_downloadview/views/base.py" in get
  170.         return self.render_to_response() File "/Users/michael/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_downloadview/views/base.py" in render_to_response
  154.             self.file_instance = self.get_file()

Exception Type: TypeError at /dm/download/5/ Exception Value: get_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace! We need to see how you call `get_file()`!

Comment: I've updated the post with the traceback.

Comment: how does `VirtualDownloadView` look like?

Comment: VirtualDownloadView is an installed library. https://github.com/benoitbryon/django-downloadview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem figured out. Basically, Django puts those named URL parameters in kwargs.

```
class DownloadJobResults(VirtualDownloadView):

    def get_file(self):

        print "Job is {}".format(self.kwargs.get("job",None))

        file = StringIO.StringIO()
        file.write("test 1,2,3,4\n")
        file.write("test 5,6,7,8\n")
        file.seek(0)
        return VirtualFile(file, name='sweet.txt')
```